# Wordpress - is_page_conditional

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I am struggling really hard with the `is_page_template` Conditional.

The problem is that when I "include" my template functions file (`country_template_functions.php`) into my `functions.php` file, the `is_page_template` conditional doesn't work anymore.
If I remove the "include(template...)" from my `functions.php` it does work again, but this is no solution since the file has to be included into the functions.php to make it work.

Can anyone explain me what might be wrong?
The is_page conditional works in both cases.

```
if (file_exists(THESIS_CUSTOM . '/country_template_functions.php')){
    include(THESIS_CUSTOM . '/country_template_functions.php');
}

function test() {
    if ( is_page_template( "country_template.php" ) ){
        echo "is page template works";
    }
}
add_action('thesis_hook_before_header','test');
```

I am using the Thesis Theme.

**EDIT:**
This seems to cause the problem but not sure exactly why. It causes that I cannot use the `is_page_template` after the `thesis_hook_before_content_area`

```
add_action('thesis_hook_before_content_area',     'country_page_template_swap_before_content');

function country_page_template_swap_before_content(){
    if (is_page()) {
        global $post;
        global $swapped_post;
        $page_template = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
        if($page_template == 'country_template.php'){
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'custom_template.php');
            $swap_id = time();
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_country_template_swapped', $swap_id);
            $swapped_post = $post;
        }
        else{
            $template_swapped = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_country_template_swapped', true);
            if(!empty($template_swapped)){
                $swapped_post = $post;
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Swap the order around. Sounds like there's an error in the file you're including.

Comment: Indeed swapping it actually makes it work.
Wondering now whats wrong with my template file.          Because I would need to use the conditional tag within my template files too.
I precisely followed this guide in creating the template:
https://alextheafrican.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/add-a-custom-page-template-to-wordpress-thesis-theme/
Are there any errors in his code?